# Is there a way for gmm in R to return parameters even if the covariance matrix is numerically singular?

Tags: r, generalized-moments

I'm trying to estimate a nonlinear GMM model with a large parameter space and a large data set. The numerical computation takes a extremely long time and I have been using small subsamples (which also take a long time) to calibrate the model. I'm getting to a point of including a large number of dummies, many of which are removed to reduce multicollinearity, yet I'm starting to get numerically singular matrix error

```
Error in solve.default(w, gbar) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.20741e-27
```

The `solve.default(w, gbar)` inputs suggest that the error is occurring during the computation of the covariance matrix. With a small subsample, the model could be overfitted, but the error persists even if I raise the number of observations a few hundreds above the number of parameters. The `gmm` function is set up as below:

```
res<-gmm(g,x,init,type="twoStep", wmatrix="optimal", optfct="nlminb", prewhite = 0, 
         lower = lb, upper = ub,
         control = list(eval.max = 1000, iter.max = 1000, abs.tol = tols, 
         rel.tol = tols),
         tol=tols)
```

where various tolerances are set to `tols=1e-15`, and I don't think any smaller number would help in this situation.

I understand that most of the CPU time is spent on numerically approximating the gradient matrix and the computing time can be drastically reduced, with accuracy increased, if $\nabla G/\nabla \Theta_0$ is provided. Unfortunately, the partials of the moment conditions are not analytically tractable. As a result, running the full dataset every time really is not a feasible strategy given the computational complexity of the model.

I'm wondering if there's a way to configure `gmm` such that it returns the some estimation results even if it cannot calculate the covariance matrix. Perhaps using `nlminb` can give me at least the parameters, but more would be better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some of the optimizers (selected through `optfct`) have the option `hessian=FALSE` so try adding `hessian=FALSE` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 approaches worked for me:

1st: just run the `nlminb` to obtain the parameters (with identity weighting matrix):

```
nlmg <- function(beta){

  gv <- as.matrix(colMeans(g1(beta,x)))

  norm(t(gv)%*%gv,"F")
}

nlmr <- nlminb(init,nlmg,lower = lb, upper = ub)
```

2nd: turn trace on. In the control list:

```
gmm(g1,x,...,control = list(trace = 1,...))
```